# how to fix finfo error in Laravel production?

Tags: laravel, cpanel

[image]

I am getting this error when I am using Storage::URL() in my laravel App in cPanel and I have installed the fileinfo extension

Answer (score 0):

You must enable fileinfo extension in php.ini as well.

If you are using cPanel, you can check here: https://www.shorttutorials.com/control-panel/enable-php-fileinfo-extension.html

Comment: i have it enabled and i am still getting the same error in my laravel app

Comment: I have the same error, were you able to resolve this issue?